# How to use date parameters in the /questions API?

Tags: support, api

When using /questions (e.g. [like this](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions#page=1&fromdate=2017-06-22&todate=2017-06-25&order=desc&sort=activity&filter=default&site=stackoverflow&run=true))), dates are represented by a number.
I'd like to know how I can convert a number to a date. For example if I have 1293840000, what date does it represent?

Answer (score 1):

The number you're looking for is the [Unix timestamp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time), the number of seconds since January 1st, 1970, 12am UTC.
So 1293840000 represents Saturday, January 1, 2011 12:00:00 AM. This is [documented in the API as well](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/dates):

> All dates in the API are in unix epoch time, which is the number of seconds since midnight UTC January 1st, 1970.

You can use an online converter like [this one](https://www.epochconverter.com/) to manually convert from and to human readable dates, and your programming of choice certainly has functions for this as well.